# Button Links on hover and on-clicked to be different

Tags: html, hyperlink, hover

How to create a button that show an url (at browser status bar) on mouse hover on that is different from the url on clicking the button. Please refer to http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35 for example.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** solution changed after author clarified his question.

This link will display 'yahoo.com' on hover, but it'll open 'google.com' when clicked.

```
<a href="http://yahoo.com" onclick="window.location.href='http://google.com'; return false;">Link</a>
```

The key is to return false from 'onclick' callback - it prevents browser from further processing event.

Comment: hi, Thanks for taking the effort to answer my question. You will notice that when you mouse hover over the link at http://www.polyvore.com/bags/shop?category_id=35, it will show that it is link from www.farfetch.com but when you click on it its in fact link to http://click.linksynergy.com/link?id=Hy3bqNL2jtQ&murl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.farfetch.com%2Fshopping%2Fwomen%2Fitem10347263.aspx&offerid=183381.10347263&type=15&u1=c5f004413fd343cbbc889138caf9d2a9. I would like to know how to achieve this but I am not concerning about the link colour.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the comment, your question wasn't very clear on that. I've change the answer, hope it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the effort to help again. I copied and pasted the code that you provided on a wordpress post to try. However, the link goes to yahoo.com instead of google.com

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this on button tag.

Instead use anchor link and gave some awesome css so link will look like button. If you will see view source or see in firebug you will see they use anchor link and applied some style so it look like button and that is not a big deal in today time.

**OR**

you need to write javascript that enable you to set status bar across browser.